# Why does matching clauses order matter when matching a map?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.match

Given `x` and `y`, both designed to match a map with the same matching clauses. The only difference is in the order of the clauses:

```clj
(ns so.example
  (:require
   [clojure.core.match :refer [match]]))

(defn x [m]
  (match m
    {:a _} :a0
    {:a _ :b _} :ab0))

(defn y [m]
  (match m
    {:a _ :b _} :ab0
    {:a _} :a0))
```

I want to match `{:a 1 :b 2}`:

```clj
(x {:a 1 :b 2})
;=> :a0
(y {:a 1 :b 2})
;=> :ab0
```

The function `y` has produced the expected result for the given map.

Admittedly I may not understand [how the algorithm works](https://github.com/clojure/core.match/wiki/Understanding-the-algorithm) but I was under the impression that `clojure.core.match` would somehow work out that `{:a _ :b _}` is somewhat more specific than `{:a _}` and would therefore try that first.

Which is why I'm surprised to see that the order of the matching clauses seems to matter.

Why is that or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would be really surprised, if clojure.core.match would _not_ follow the tradition of using the best, first match in order (like in all (?) the other programming languages, that support pattern matching)

Comment: @cfrick Sorry I wasn't aware this was a common practice. The article I mentioned in my post hints at some pre-processing of the rules and therefore it didn't seem it would _simply_ go through the clauses one by one in order. I suppose I must have misunderstood it.

Comment: You've misunderstood the article. "The semantics of pattern matching dictate that we evaluate the clauses one at a time from top to bottom" is the behavior that pattern matching must present. The intent of the article is to describe ways you can still get that behavior with a less naive implementation, letting you save work without changing the results.

Comment: Thanks @amalloy that was really helpful. By the way do you have any articles you would recommend reading about pattern matching?

Answer (score 1):

The way the match calculates a pattern score can't discern `{:a _}` from `{:a _ :b _}`, which it probably should. What you can do instead, is to tell it specifically there is no :b in the map.

```
(m/match [{:a 1 :b 2}]
         [({:a _} :only [:a])] :a0
         [{:a _ :b _}] :ab0)
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the `:only` keyword. It's something I should have considered.